# foreach with variable name equal to field name

Tags: java, foreach, intellij-idea

Found interesting thing while compile the following piece of code:

```
1    class A {
2        
3     private B line;
4   
5     public void foo() {
6       for (Integer line : line.getElements()) {
7    
8       }
9     }
10    }
11    
12    class B {
13    
14      List<Integer> getElements() {
15         return null; // doesn't matter
16      }
17    }
```

Pay attention to line 6: we see that variable name is equal to field name. IntelliJ Idea 11 ignores this and think there is no trouble here. But java compiler tells me that 'line doesn't have method getElements'. So, two questions:

1. Should I submit a bugreport in Idea?
2. Why the error message from Java is like this? Isn't it able to detect the mistake? What mechanism is working here? Eclipsing of field variable?

Comment: The IntelliJ Idea behavior should be consistent with the javac compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may be a bug in the Java compiler you are using. According to the [Java Language Specification (section 14.14.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), the scope of the variable in an enhanced `for` statement is the contained statement. (This seems to exclude the iterable or array expression to the right of the `:`.)

You can work around the problem by using `this.line.getElements()`.

**EDIT**
Just for kicks, I submitted this as a bug report to Sun. We'll see whether the Java engineers think it's a bug in the JLS or in javac (or if they have some other explanation). The bug id is [7139681](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7139681), although it won't be posted to the external database for a couple of days.

Comment: @Tedd: Can you elaborate "contained statement"?

Comment: I'm not sure the spec says that. "The scope of a local variable declared in the FormalParameter part of an enhanced for statement (§14.14) is the contained Statement" - problem: there is no "FormalParameter" part in an enhanced for AFAICT.

Comment: @Mat, specs says that and I am confused too.

Comment: @thinksteep - The contained statement is the statement that is executed 0 or more times under control of the `for` condition. (The part of the `for` statement that comes after the parenthetical part; the part that's often inside braces `{}`.)

Comment: @Mat - I agree; the spec seems to be poorly written here (which is a bit of a surprise). There is a _FormalParameter_ part of a `try` statement (in the `catch` clause - Section 14.20) which appears to have the same syntax as the part before the colon in an enhanced `for` statement. Perhaps the terminology in the spec came from there.

Answer (score 7):

If you declare local variable (which is what you have done) with the same name as field, than you can access the field variable as `this.name`.

```
for (Integer line : this.line.getElements()) {
}
```

Comment: [Section 14.14.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) seems to suggest that the scope of the local variable is only the enclosed statement (the part between the `{}`), and does not include the expression inside the parentheses to the right of the `:`.

Answer (score -2):

When you use IntelliJ it parses all the files automatically.  However with `javac` it might not compile all the programs, esp if they have been compiled before.

Say you have class B (without the getElements()) and you compile it.  Later you add the method and only compile A, it will complain that B doesn't have that method because the last time you compiled it, there was no such method.

The way around this is to delete all the *.class files before compiling or using a build tool like maven.

Comment: Not the case. I made clean and whole rebuild. no effect.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with OP's question. The problem can be reduced to a single class: `public class Bug {
 int[] index;

 public void bug() {
  for (int index : index) {
  }
 }
}`

Comment: It's not clear that it's a mistake in the code. There's an inconsistency between the JLS and the behavior of javac. Under a strict reading of the JLS, the code should be legal. (However, section 14.14.2 of the JLS seems somewhat poorly written; it uses a term that doesn't seem to be defined, at least not there.)